# Wrong number of arguments to IF

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, gs-vlookup, nested-if

With the formula below, I keep receiving the error "Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but received 5 arguments."

Where have I gone wrong? It works up until a certain point and then the code throw up the above error... Am i missing a comma or bracket somewhere?

Any help greatly appreciated :)

```
=arrayformula(If(G5 <> "",if(H5 = "Y",if(C6 = "Sub-Total", ttime($M$3,vlookup(B5,Lookup!$A:$I,3,0)),if(AND(C7 = "Sub-Total",B6 <>"",B5 <>""),ttime($M$3,vlookup(B6,Lookup!$A:$I,3,0),vlookup(B5,Lookup!$A:$I,3,0)),if(AND(C8 = "Sub-Total",B7 <> "", B6 <> "",B5 <>""),ttime($M$3,vlookup(B7,Lookup!$A:$I,3,0),vlookup(B6,Lookup!$A:$I,3,0),vlookup(B5,Lookup!$A:$I,3,0)),if(AND(C9 = "Sub-Total",B8 <> "", B7 <> "",B6 <>"",B5 <> ""),ttime($M$3,vlookup(B8,Lookup!$A:$I,3,0),vlookup(B7,Lookup!$A:$I,3,0),vlookup(B6,Lookup!$A:$I,3,0)),vlookup(B5,Lookup!$A:$I,3,0)),if(AND(C10 = "Sub-Total",B9 <> "", B8 <> "",B7 <>"",B6 <> "",B5 <> ""),ttime($M$3,vlookup(B9,Lookup!$A:$I,3,0),vlookup(B8,Lookup!$A:$I,3,0),vlookup(B7,Lookup!$A:$I,3,0)),vlookup(B6,Lookup!$A:$I,3,0)),vlookup(B5,Lookup!$A:$I,3,0))))+IF(C6 = "sub-total","",if(B5 <> "", G6 * 3,""))+IF(C6 = "sub-total","",if(B5 <> "", "15","")),"Not Despatched"),""))
```

Comment: Is =TTIME() a custom function?  Could you share a sample sheet that would make it easier to see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF(G5<>"", 
 IF(H5="Y",
 IF(C6="Sub-Total",                                               TTIME($M$3, VLOOKUP(B5, Lookup!$A:$I, 3, 0)),
 IF(AND(C7="Sub-Total", B6<>"", B5<>""),                          TTIME($M$3, VLOOKUP(B6, Lookup!$A:$I, 3, 0), 
                                                                              VLOOKUP(B5, Lookup!$A:$I, 3, 0)), 
 IF(AND(C8="Sub-Total", B7<>"", B6<>"", B5<>""),                  TTIME($M$3, VLOOKUP(B7, Lookup!$A:$I, 3, 0), 
                                                                              VLOOKUP(B6, Lookup!$A:$I, 3, 0), 
                                                                              VLOOKUP(B5, Lookup!$A:$I, 3, 0)),
 IF(AND(C9="Sub-Total", B8<>"", B7<>"", B6<>"", B5<>""),          TTIME($M$3, VLOOKUP(B8, Lookup!$A:$I, 3, 0), 
                                                                              VLOOKUP(B7, Lookup!$A:$I, 3, 0),
                                                                              VLOOKUP(B6, Lookup!$A:$I, 3, 0),
                                                                              VLOOKUP(B5, Lookup!$A:$I, 3, 0)),
 IF(AND(C10="Sub-Total", B9<>"", B8<>"", B7<>"", B6<>"", B5<>""), TTIME($M$3, VLOOKUP(B9, Lookup!$A:$I, 3, 0),
                                                                              VLOOKUP(B8, Lookup!$A:$I, 3, 0), 
                                                                              VLOOKUP(B7, Lookup!$A:$I, 3, 0),
                                                                              VLOOKUP(B6, Lookup!$A:$I, 3, 0),
                                                                              VLOOKUP(B5, Lookup!$A:$I, 3, 0)))))))+
 IF(C6="sub-total",,
 IF(B5<>"", G6*3, ))+
 IF(C6="sub-total",,
 IF(B5<>"", "15", )), "Not Despatched"), ))
```

[image: 0]